# Google Places API Nearby Search to return custom data

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Referring from the Google Places API `Nearby Search Requests` sample code below:

```
///......

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

//....
```

Is it possible to `request a custom lists of store data` that is coming from a database for example?

If not, then what could be the best alternative? 
Any help is greatly appreciated. TIA

source: [Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)

Comment: Google doesn't have your data, if it is in your database, you need to write your own query that returns that data.

Answer (score 0):

No, all of the request data comes from Google using their Places API.  In order to request custom data, you would have to roll your own search function to look through the database.

Have a look at [SO: PHP AJAX Database search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204158/php-ajax-autocomplete-form-mysql-database) for one example of how to search a database for values (This one performs autocomplete based on input)